# Using GitHub OAuth for Superset

Tags: flask, oauth, apache-superset, github-oauth

I am running superset from a container on a server and I am trying to use GitHub OAuth for user signup/login.

Unfortunately I got it working to the point where I can see the "*SIGN IN WITH GITHUB*" button. However when I click it, the website populates a label that reads "*The request to sign in was denied.*".

Looking at the docker logs of the app, I've tracked down the issue to a Flask error:

```
ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.views:Error authorizing OAuth access token: redirect_uri_mismatch: The redirect_uri MUST match the registered callback URL for this application.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I believe it may be because I configured the wrong Authorization Callback URL when creating the OAuth app on GitHub. Does superset have a default Authorization Callback URL that I'm supposed to use? I have mine currently set as https://my-domain.com/oauth-authorized/github.

My other theory is that the `custom_sso_security_manager.py` is not configured properly due to me using the default values. If that's the case, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is my **superset config file**:

```
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
from custom_sso_security_manager import CustomSsoSecurityManager
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSsoSecurityManager
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {   'name':'github',
        'token_key':'access_token',
        'icon':'fa-github',
        'remote_app': {
            'client_id':'"#############################',
            'client_secret':'##############################',
            'client_kwargs':{
                'scope':'read'
            },
            'access_token_method':'POST',
            'access_token_params':{
            'client_id':'#############################'
            },
            'access_token_headers':{
            'Authorization': 'Basic Base64EncodedClientIdAndSecret'
            },
            'api_base_url':'https://api.github.com/user',
            'access_token_url':'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',
            'authorize_url':'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize',
            'redirect_uri':'https://my-domain.com/oauth-authorized/github'
        }
    }
]

# Will allow user self registration, allowing to create Flask users from Authorized User
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True

# The default user self registration role
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = ["sql_lab","workshop"]
```

And here is my `custom_sso_security_manager.py`:
import logging
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager

```
class CustomSsoSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):

    def oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None):
        logging.debug("Oauth2 provider: {0}.".format(provider))
        if provider == 'github':
            # As example, this line request a GET to base_url + '/' + userDetails with Bearer  Authentication,
    # and expects that authorization server checks the token, and response with user details
            me = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].get('userDetails').data
            logging.debug("user_data: {0}".format(me))
            return { 'name' : me['name'], 'email' : me['email'], 'id' : me['user_name'], 'username' : me['user_name'], 'first_name':me['nickname'], 'last_name':me['nickname']}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must have resolved your issue since, but I had the same issue so I share the solution.

The error `redirect_uri_mismatch` is caused by Superset not sending the same `redirect_uri` than the one configured in github. You can check in the web browser the real `redirect_uri` sent to GitHub and check if it the right one.

The parameter `redirect_uri` seems to be ignored by Superset we can omit it. The URL is created dynamically and might be different than expected. For example, if Superset is behind a reverse proxy that terminates the SSL connection, Superset will send a `http://` URI instead of `https://`. By adding `ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True` in the configuration, this issue is solved.

Here is a working configuration example:

```py
# This will make sure the redirect_uri is properly computed, even with SSL offloading
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True

from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {   'name':'github',
        'token_key':'access_token',
        'icon':'fa-github',
        'remote_app': {
            'client_id':'"#############################',
            'client_secret':'##############################',
            'client_kwargs':{
                'scope':'read:org'
            },
            'api_base_url':'https://api.github.com/',
            'access_token_url':'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',
            'authorize_url':'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize',
        }
    }
]

# Will allow user self registration, allowing to create Flask users from Authorized User
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True

# The default user self registration role
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = ["sql_lab","workshop"]
```